# What's the meaning of a sentence by a manga author? 「もともとイラスト畑の人間なので...」

Tags: meaning

> **もともとイラスト畑の人間なので**、全体の流れよりも
> 1コマごとの絵に意識が持っていかれる事が多くて大変でした。
> 1コマ描くのに一日かかったのもあったりして....
>
> 漫画って難しいですね！
>
> それでは、この本を手に取ってくださり まことにありがとうございました！

I'm having a hard time understanding the sentence in bold. What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ～畑の actually simply means "(in) the field of ～", where this "field" refers to fields of expertise/business rather than fields of vegetables. It's a fairly slangy way of saying someone's specialty. Of course a mangaka needs to draw much more pictures than an illustrator.

> もともとイラスト畑の人間なので
>   Originally I specialized in illustrations, so ...
>   Originally I was doing business as an illustrator, so ...